# Catel WPF - Lag when changing screen

Tags: wpf, catel

I'm using Catel in my application and I have problem with changing screens.

I have a ribbon navigation and a ContentPresenter for a screen. When I click ribbon button, I change ActiveView property in my ViewModel

It looks like this:

```
<ContentPresenter Margin="5 5 5 0" Content="{Binding ActiveView, Converter={StaticResource ViewModelToViewConverter}}" />
```

`ActiveView` is a ViewModel of my UserControl for specific view.

The problem is, that everytime I change screen (click ribbon button), I have a lag ~100ms which is very irritating.

I have also tried with `DataTemplates` for ContentPresenter, but there is no Performance boost with it.

Is there a way of boot performance of this? Maybe a way to pre-construct view, and then only show it? (because right now View is being constructed everytime I click a ribbon button)

Of course I'm checking it on Release build (on debug there is much more lag) :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [performance considerations in the docs](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Performance+considerations). A few hints:

1. Have you tried without a debugger attached?
2. Are there log listeners doing a lot of work?
3. Enable [Api cop](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/ApiCop) to see what features you are not using but are taking time. Then you can disable them.

Probably it's the control looking for the InfoBarMessageControl (which you can simply disable).